# how upload image to mongodb buffer with react in client side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, buffer

I am using multer

```
  const upload = multer({
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1000000
    },
    fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
        if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/)) {
            return cb(new Error('Please upload an image'))


        cb(undefined, true)
    }
})
```

the server side,using express and multer I want to store the image to mongodb in buffer type

```
router.post('/users/me/avatar', auth, upload.single('avatar'), async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file)
    const buffer = await sharp(req.file.buffer).resize({ width: 250, height: 250 }).png().toBuffer()
    req.user.avatar = buffer
    await req.user.save()
    res.send()
}, (error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(400).send({ error: error.message })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You want your image in base 64 ? you gonna need to use [Jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp)

`npm install --save jimp`

```
const Jimp = require('jimp');

Jimp.read(req.file.path)
  .then(image => {
    return image.getBase64(Jimp.AUTO, (err, res) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err);

      // you launch your mongodb save with res
      return res; 
    });
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/issues/522#issuecomment-411246785

Comment: I think this a server-side code I have already my code above I used multer and sharp to resize the image and I test it in postman and it works perfectly just want to implement a client-side with react for it I don't know how to convert the image to buffer type in client side  and save it in mongodb?

Comment: You can't reach mongoDB from your client side, it's impossible. Are you telling me you've opened backend routes in your frontend ??? yes it's possible as long as you don't use react-router. Try my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
const imageMimeTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/jif']

function saveCover(book, cover) {
    if(cover == null) return
    if(cover != null && imageMimeTypes.includes(cover.type)) {
        book.coverImage = new Buffer.from(cover.data, 'base64')
        book.coverImageType = cover.type
    }
}
```